# Django communicating with another python application?

Tags: django, python-3.x, asynchronous, server, microservices

Is it possible to have django running on the server and one application from django inter communicating with another python process say that I developed and fetching a response from it or even make it just do a particular action?

It can be synchronous or asynchronous; I have some idea of being asynchronous where some package like hendrix, crossbar.io or even celery can be used. But I don't understand what would be the name for this inter-communication and how should I plan the architecture for this.

Going around my head I have the two following situations I'm seeking a plan to be developed:

**1.**

Say I have django and an e-mail sender with the python package smtp. A user making a request to a view would make django execute my python module I developed for sending an email to a particular user (with a smpt server from google/gmail). It could be synchronous or asynchronous.

OR

**2**

I have django (some application) and I want it to communicate with some server I maintain; say for making this server execute some code or just fetch a file (if it is an ftp server). Is this an appropriate situation to point to the term 'microservices'? Or there is another term or workaround here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first solution would be called an installable python module, just like any package you install with pip. You can have this as a separate module if you need your code to be re-usable across multiple or just future projects.

Your second solution would be a microservice. This will require setting your small module as a service that could have a REST API to communicate with and make it do whatever you intend it to do.

If your question is "what is the right approach" then I would tell you it depends on your use case. If this is just some re-usable code that you don't want to repeat over and over through our project then just make it into a separate module. While if this is a service that you expect other built services will use and rely on, then just make it into a microservice. You can use a microframework such as Flask for easier and faster setup of your service. Otherwise, if it's just some code that you will use once and serves a single functionality on your application then just write it and keep it there.

There are no rules or standards on which approach should be taken. I personally judge things depending on the use-case.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for clearing out some concepts and terms! I'm intrigued how would then I implement this module in a django view: import the module's function and execute it within django's synchronous context? This sounds logical. However, if I want the module I created to execute in another separate process, then this would be "Asynchronous" and I should look for asynchronous ways like "celery" for handling this, right?

Comment: Yes, you will need a queue and worker to do that asynchronously for you.

Comment: hi @devdob can you please explore second solution with brief example